# Object to List<T>

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a method that takes an `object` as a parameter (this cannot be changed):

```
public class MyClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    public override void DoFoo(object value)
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

And I know for the particular class the `object` will be a `List<T>` where `T` is unknown.

What I want to do is convert `object` to `List<T>` so that I can sort it. Something like:

```
public override void DoFoo(object value)
{
    var list = value as List<T>;   // obviously not valid!
    list.Sort();
    // ...
}
```

Is there any way to do this? Note that I can't make my class `MyClass<T>` because the class itself has to be used in as an argument to an attribute and those can't use type parameters:

```
public class ParentClass<T>
{
    [SomeAttr(typeof(MyClass<T>))]    // also not valid
    public List<T> MyProperty
}
```

The only solution I currently have is to (ab)use `dynamic`:

```
var list = value as dynamic;
list.Sort();
```

But I'm not too happy about that.

Comment: Back to basics! `List<T>` implements `IList`.

Comment: @leppie: That was my first thought, but `IList` doesn't have a `Sort`.

Comment: You would use `ArrayList.Adapter(list).Sort()`

Comment: @leppie: That's an idea. Have to admit that's new to me.

Comment: @leppie: If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it. I think it's safer than using `dynamic`. As long as my objects can implement `IComparable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is useful sometimes to use the old non-generic interfaces if a generic type argument cannot be resolved.

In this case, one can use the following:

```
public override void DoFoo(object value)
{
    var list = ArrayList.Adapter((IList)value);
    list.Sort();
    // ...
}
```